# Refresh iBeacon state

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am newbie with iBeacon and need some help. Already found some useful info from other topics but still searching for answers.

Is there a way to receive notification about my state at position right after app is killed or after I switch ON bluetooth? Now I got notifications only after state changes.

Example: I need to have notification when I got to point 'A'. But I got there and realized that my bluetooth is OFF. I switched bluetooth ON and didn't get anything because iBeacon thought I am 'INSIDE' from beginning. This happens when app is not foreground (but not 100% times, sometimes iBeacon 'rescan' and send his state again).

I need to somehow manually refresh iBeacon state and get methods didDetermineState or didRangeBeacons to work. I tried to stop and start monitoring after app is killed to forces the notification, but doesn't seem it works. I know there is a way to get this 'refresh' after turning ON display, but it could be perfect to also get it in other situations when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of location and beacon events can wake up an app that is running in the background, but **relatively few events are sent to apps that have been killed via the task switcher or were never launched since boot.**

The only bluetooth events capable of launching a non running app are:

- didEnterRegion (for CLBeaconRegions)
- didExitRegion (for CLBeaconRegions)

Other events received only by foreground/background running apps:

- didDetermineStateForRegion
- CoreBluetooth device discovery
- CoreBluetooth power state changes

The last one is the event you care about, but it just won't be sent to apps that are not running.  One alternative may be to rely on other location events like Significant Location Change, which launches a non-running app when the user moves "significantly" (e.g. to the next cell tower).  You could register for these events and check Bluetooth state at that time.  This may be the best you can do.